# Minha listagem esta demorando muito para carregar

Tags: php

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">ID</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Cpf</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Cidade</th>
                <th>Filho Data Nascimento</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>Cadastro</th>
                <th>Usuário</th>
                <th class="text-center">Ações</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            $mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dbax");

            $query = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM c_endereco INNER JOIN c_cliente ON c_cliente.idunico_cliente = c_endereco.idunico_cliente INNER JOIN c_cadastro ON c_cadastro.idunico_cliente = c_endereco.idunico_cliente INNER JOIN c_entrevista ON c_entrevista.idunico_cliente = c_endereco.idunico_cliente INNER JOIN c_finalizou ON c_finalizou.idunico_cliente = c_endereco.idunico_cliente ORDER BY c_cliente.ID DESC LIMIT 10;");        
            while($row = $query->fetch_array()){            
            $c_link = "http://localhost/painel/redireciona.php?id=".$row['idunico_cliente']."&cep=".$row['cliente_cep'];

            <tr>
                <td class="text-center" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $c_link; ?>');"><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
                <td style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $c_link; ?>');"><?php echo $row['cliente_nome']; ?></td>
                <td style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $c_link; ?>');"><?php echo $row['cliente_cpf']; ?></td>
                <td style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $c_link; ?>');"><?php echo $row['cliente_estado']; ?></td>
                <td style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $c_link; ?>');"><?php echo $row['cliente_cidade']; ?></td>
                <td style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $c_link; ?>');"><?php echo $row['cliente_filho_nascimento']; ?></td>
                <td style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $c_link; ?>');"><?php echo $row['cliente_categoria']; ?></td> 
                <td style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $c_link; ?>');"><?php echo $row['cliente_cadastro_data']; ?></td>
                <td style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $c_link; ?>');"><?php if (!empty($row['cliente_user_resp'])) {  ?><small style="color:red" ><?php echo $row['cliente_user_resp']; ?></small><?php }else{ ?><small style="color:green" >Disponivel</small><?php } ?></td>

                <td class="td-actions text-right">
                    <button type="button" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-info btn-just-icon btn-sm">
                        <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Uso para criar uma listagem com table, quando passa de 1000 ~ 3000 cadastros no banco de dados ele demora para carregar até mesmo cai, mesmo colocando LIMIT oque posso fazer para solucionar isso?

Comment: João, cole todo o seu código, pois o problema pode estar na estrutura antes ou até depois da consulta no banco.

Comment: Ok vou mudar agora

Comment: Pronto, esse é um sistema para um painel interno, pretendo mudar para PDO em breve mas por enquanto preciso apenas que ele funcione bem

Comment: Aparentemente seu script é bem básico, então não se vê problema aparente. Se você executa a query direto no banco, fica lento ? Teste executar a query remotamente, direto no banco localmente, etc, assim pode encontrar onde pode estar o problema, já que no seu script quase certeza que não é. Quanto ao PDO, pesquise bem a real necessidade disso, pois ele em partes é mais lento por conta de usar mais passos, e geralmente ninguém utiliza vários bancos.

Comment: Então eu iria usar PDO para aprimorar o trabalho mas em questão de segurança ou necessidade não precisaria por ser um sistema interno sem acesso ao publico

Comment: Eu removi o inner join e ele esta carregando normal! Mas não da pra usar sem inner join, só se tiver outro metodo de selecionar varias tabelas

Comment: Você precisa ir por partes. Primeiro, testa direto no banco de dados na máquina local. Se não der lentidão, testa em outra com acesso direto ao banco, remotamente. Se não der, testa seu script em outra máquina. Pode ser problema no seu banco, no seu php, etc (tenta reiniciar serviços do banco, apache, etc)

Comment: Testei em 3 locais diferentes, servidor cloud LINUX, meu computador, e hospedagem padrão, todas o mesmo poblema!

Comment: Tem o phpmyadmin no servidor ? Testou dele ?

Comment: Tem sim, phpmyadmin ta normal, e outra coisa quando eu faço apenas 1 inner join sem  while ele carrega normal!

Comment: Provavelmente é lentidão no serviço do php, porque se está normal no banco, eu focaria nisso.